# Executing some code only once in a Thread region

Tags: java, performance, openmp, hpc, performance-measuring

In a certain part of a Java code that i am working, i need to place a timer inside a `run()` method. Each thread will execute all code inside `run()`. But i need to start measuring after block (1) and before block of code (2) so the timer needs to be triggered there.

```
for (int i = 0; i < total_threads-1; i++){
   final int id = i+1;          
   th[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {              
       public final void run(){
             /* ... block of code (1) executed by multiple threads ... */

             /* How can i start this counter only once? */
             final long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();

             /* ... another block of code (2) executed by multiple threads i need to measure!!! ... */
       }
    });
    th[i].start();
}

for(int i = 0 ; i < total_threads-1 ; i++) {
    try {
           th[i].join();
        }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}

final long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println((end-begin) / 1000.0);
```

But all the threads will have their own `begin` variable and start the counter which is a problem because `System.currentTimeMillis()` should be triggered once and not by many threads.
I probably could separate the code of `run()` in two different parallel regions but would imply creating the threads twice which would be unacceptable (in terms of performance). 
There is a similar technique of OpenMP directive `#pragma omp master` for Java using Java threads?
How can i measure the time correctly here?

Comment: What is the point having seperate begin variable for every threads which has same value System.currentTimeMillis (As you want it should be triggered only once ! )??

Answer (score 1):

You can check the thread ID to execute prefer line once:

```
if (id == YOUR_THREAD_ID) 
{
     begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: This probably won't work, since `begin` must be final, so can't be modified by the child threads.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would just be to record the time in the master thread (i.e. the thread which creates all the children) instead of in the children themselves.

But if you really want to start the timer in the children (maybe there's some expensive setup?), you could use a Guava [StopWatch](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html) object.

The code would look something like:

```
StopWatch timer = StopWatch.createUnstarted();
for (int i = 0; i < total_threads-1; i++){
    final int id = i+1;
    th[i] = new Thread(() -> {
        /* ... block of code (1) executed by multiple threads ... */

        try {
            synchronized (timer) {
                timer.start();
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // ignore; the watch is already started
        }

        /* ... another block of code (2) executed by multiple threads i need to measure!!! ... */
    });
    th[i].start();
}

for(int i = 0 ; i < total_threads-1 ; i++) {
    try {
        th[i].join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}

timer.stop();

System.out.println(timer.elapsed(TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but unfortunately didn't work. Your solution results in an execution error:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: This stopwatch is already stopped."

The problem is caused by the measurement inside the run() method. If i put:
`try {
    synchronized(timerThreads){
        timerThreads.start();
        }
   }
   catch (IllegalStateException e) {}` 

Outside `run()` the program works fine but does not do what is supposed to.

Comment: Why do you want to start the timer inside the child threads? Why not just do all the timing in the master thread, as I suggested? The error you're getting suggests that your threads never started the timer. Did you wait until after the `join` to `stop` it? Do you have any child threads at all?

Comment: I actually solved the problem measuring the time of master. Didn't realised actually the master will wait the all threads finish their work so measuring the master work will do the job. Thanks for your help

Comment: @CarlosSá Feel free to mark this answer as correct. measuring everything in the master thread was what I recommended.